# Apply a non-linear `skew` transformation in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, draggable, css-transforms, non-linear

I would like to have a non-linear `skew` on an element on my page, so the skew can be algorithmically modified on an element drag to replicate the look of "Wobbly Windows" on the web. Ideally I would like to use pure JS/CSS to accomplish this, but I am willing to use a library if necessary and if anyone has a good recommendation.

This is an example of what I would like to achieve:

[image: Wobbly Windows GIF]

From all the documentation I have read, this is currently not supported. Does anyone have any creative workarounds to offer to achieve the desired effect?

This is possible to do on an SVG ([example](https://codepen.io/benjamminf/pen/oZKBEw)) with the [Warp.js](https://github.com/benjamminf/warpjs) library, but I need to apply it to a div, not an image. If there is a good way to map a div to an SVG while still keeping it interactive, that would work for my use case as well.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining a way to do this, but the two things that come to mind are maybe some 3d transformations or depending on the content of the element, creating several boxes that are the same element but showing different parts of the element, then piecing it all together and moving each element at different rates. Wouldn't be quite as smooth. Something like the strategy they use in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSWr6dkc_Xw). Hopefully that helps a bit :) specifically look at their flag demo at 26:40

Comment: @asyncawait that's an interesting suggestion, thank you! Certainly worth exploring.

Comment: Searching for 'deforming an HTML element using CSS' yields some results but I have not idea whether they are any good or not I'm afraid.

Comment: @AHaworth nice Google-Fu! I didn't try that exact verbiage, I found an interesting library called `taccgl` that may be beneficial to this scenario.